# How to get minecraft's accurate 'x' and 'y' rotations?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm attempting to recreate [this concept](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehXgXF6Lexc&index=24&list=LLklpydeHzw8EcYTSPsaMyVA&t=23s) using an 16 'x' compass rose and 25 'y' axis degree. My first attempt I already had the rotations for N, S, E, and, W as well the NE, NW, SE, and SW. Additionally, I had the 'y' axis degrees looking down. But as I research more, I found the cardinal directions were not accurate.

In the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_vertical_rotation), it states that 180.0 is north, -90.0 is east, 0.0 is south, and 90.0 is west. With that being said the appropriate command for testing facing south is `@a[ry=0,rym=-0]`. However once a player turning left meeting 0.0 the command automatically finds the player once they reached 0.9 instead of 0.0.

The same issue is the same if a player was to look up. An example is when a player were to attempt to face at 75 degree up the command to testfor such thing would be `/testfor @a[rxm=-75,rx=-75]`.

What do I need to know in order to testfor the correct and accurate intgers? Am I doing something wrong on how the order of `ry` & `rx` in each command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't test for the exact values in the selectors, as `@a[rxm=-75.0,rx=-75.0]` won't work. and the way it's found is just the way minecraft rounds those numbers, i don't think there is anything we can do about that.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily find the rotations by pressing F3 in a world and looking at where it says "Facing:". This picture shows the rotation my head is currently looking at.[image: Rotation]

Comment: The question is asking about using the rotation values in commands, which your answer doesn't address.

Comment: This actually is the rotation values, because you can type `/tp @p ~ ~ ~ -27 -7` and it will teleport you to that exact rotation. So unless I'm misunderstanding you, I believe this is correct.

Comment: I should have said command blocks. Yes they can input values from F3, but they need a way to find the find the values using the command block, e.g. check if a player is facing southeast.